# How to customize WordPress vertical menu?

Tags: customization, menus

I must make change view on the menu on the website, but I do not know how.
Can someone help me, please? How can I make a hook in function for example or another method with edit CSS file?

I want to look like this. Vertical menu on the left side.
http://html.tonatheme.com/2017/Consulted/services-single.html

Mu menu
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iduU.jpg

If someone says, step by step.

Comment: please use [SM Vertical Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sm-vertical-menu/) plugin

Comment: Hey Nikolaii, sounds like you need to style your menu so that it looks like the menu that you suggested. To do that you would need to edit your CSS only. Using the Customizer in WordPress, you should be able to add any additional CSS there. You'll just need to know what specific classes are being applied to that menu only, which you can easily determine by looking at your HTML source code.